# is 'the' an adjective? Please tell

Tags: adjectives

I've looked it up in Hindi dictionary that tells me that *the* is an adjective. I googled but couldn't get that is an adjective

Comment: *The* is an *[article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles)*, which some authorities consider a type of *[determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners)*. Articles were traditionally classified as adjectives, in that any qualifier of a noun was considered an adjective, but modern linguists use more specific terminology.

Comment: Did it only say it was an adjective, or did it say it was a determiner/article in most uses and an adjective in another? Also, when was that dictionary published?

Comment: Modern analyses of the English language tend to be a lot sounder than older ones. 'The' (and 'a / an, some, many, seventeen, these, other' ...) share some of the properties of obvious (more central) adjectives, but are so dissimilar in behaviour and role that they are now considered by almost all linguists to be best classified as different entities. Look up 'determiner' here and on the internet.

Comment: 'The' and 'a' are more like adjectives than anything else. They don't don't act in all circumstances like 'red' or 'many' so they are subcategorized with the labels 'article' or 'determiner'.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

"The" and "A" and "An" are diagrammed as adjectives, and they function to define/describe a noun. Even if they have a different title (definite/indefinite article) theya re still functionally adjectives in my book.

Comment: Time to get a different book.